# Как получить остатки по складам для комплекта через API

Tags: moysklad-json-api, moysklad-pos-api, moysklad-phone-api

Интересует возможность получить остатки по складам для комплекта через API? 
Сейчас я могу лишь достать товары с общим остатком по всем складам. И будет ли присылаться хук на комплект, если изменился остаток у товара, который входит в состав комплекта?

Answer (score 1):

Остатки по складам для комплектов получить через апи нельзя. Весь возможный функционал по раоте с остатками указан в [документации](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#header-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) по апи и в [мануале](https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/articles/203319073-%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8). Вы можете сами обойти это ограничение, посчитав остатки по комплектующим.

Comment: А если остаток одного товара из комплекта меняется, мне нужно будет после прихода хука, искать все комплекты запрашивать, а потом к них запрашивать сведения по товарам?